# other objects push on bone controlled surface?

Tags: armature

I have made a basic cardboard box model, and I'm trying to use bones for control/as a hinge.
is there a way to make other objects push on the flaps controlled by a bone or must I animate this effect manually?(i.e. dropping a bowling ball onto a close box and having it move th flaps out of the way on the way down)

[image]

Comment: Do you need to use bones? this could be more easily accomplished other ways.

Comment: you could use rigidbodys , or make a center IK rig that moves all pieces

Comment: @Knuckles209cp I don't think that would work as well as you would expect.

Comment: not necessarily need bones if there's another way to bend the flaps without going into edit mode and manually changing the shape.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I've set up a simple box that is weight painted so the main bone only influences the flap.  The tip bone is there for the IK setup.(not sure I did this entirely right since I'm still just learning this as well)

Anyways, here are a few pics.  First you can add a loopcut to the edge of the flap to limit the weight paint so the bone does not affect the rest of the box.

[image]

Now the weight paint setup.

[image]

There is an Empty added near the tip of the IK controller bone which is referenced in the IK constriant which I added to that bone as shown next.

[image]

I also added rotation locks to both bones so they can only move in one axis.  The image shows 2 places where this can be done.

[image]

Next is an animation showing the result of moving the Empty.

[image]